curl webpage and convert to markdown
having a dilemma with downloading webpages and converting them to markdown, for example:
F=$(curl -O --silent https://www.guru3d.com/story/msi-teases-spatium-m560-ssd-with-innovative-nonmetallic-vc-cooling-technology | pandoc --extract-media="./"${F%.*}"_media" --from html --to markdown_strict -o "${F%.*}.md")

HTML file downloads fine but the md file that gets created is not given proper name and is of no content.
What is wrong in this syntax? Is there maybe some better or easier way of downloading webpages, converting them to markdown and storing html page images locally?

It looks like you're tring to refer to variable $F in the same line of code that is setting $F. That's not going to work.

But also, in a context where $F is set,  you should say "./${F%.*}_media" rather than "./"${F%.*}"_media".

I think you should use wget for downloading all pages requisites.
You can use this shell script by changing the $url variable
#!/bin/sh
url="https://www.guru3d.com/story/msi-teases-spatium-m560-ssd-with-innovative-nonmetallic-vc-cooling-technology"
outfile="$(basename "$url")"
wget -nd -p -R woff2,js,css -P webpage $url
pandoc --from html --to markdown_strict-raw_html --extract-media="./"${outfile%.*}"_media" -o "${outfile%.*}.md" webpage/"$outfile"

These are the options for wget

-p: download page requisites
-nd: no directories (all in the same level)
-P webpage: download everything in webpage directory
-R woff2,js,css: Reject unneeded extensions

And in pandoc I use almost the same options but

--to markdown_strict-raw_html: to remove the inline html embedded in markdown

Hope this can help you

much obliged, it is a solid way of downloading websites for archiving.
